# Using Redis on shared server with multiple Laravel application

Tags: php, redis, queue, cpanel, laravel-5.5

We have hosted two laravel application on one server. Installed redis & supervisor.
In supervisor configuration (/etc/supervisord.conf) added two configuration

Application 1 configuration

```
[program:app1-supervisor]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php //path/to/application/1/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ladybirq
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/application/1/worker.log
```

Application 2 configuration

```
[program:app2-supervisor]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php //path/to/application/2/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ladybirq
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/application/2/worker.log
```

When application 1 sends email, It sends from application 2 mail configuration.
Email configuration is stored in database and on fly application set in the configuration

Example

```
$email = Email::first();
config(“mail.driver.$email->driver”);
```

So some values in the application 1 email get replaced with application 2 values.
Not sure where I am going wrong.

Have anyone configured Redis on the single server with multiple applications. Both our application are same.

We are using cPanel on this server and both the application are hosted in different cPanel account on the same server

Comment: Setup both applications to use a different redis database.